# iOS SystemSoundID does not work on iPod 4, but works on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod-touch

Why SystemSoundID work on iPhone and not on iPod?

I've searched the Apple docs. and googled but have found nothing.
My app plays .m4a sound files using SystemSoundID on iPhone gen 4 (iOS 5.1) OK, but not on iPod gen 4 (iOS 5.1) nor iPod gen 2 (iOS 4.2).  Sounds don't play, and completion callback fails.

AVAudioPlayer works fine on on all, which I use for continually playing background music, but I need the SystemSoundID AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion in order to queue up back to back sounds.

I would use AVAudioPlayer to play the back to back sound files but I cannot find a completion callback function for it.

Answer (score 0):

Settings->Sounds->Ringer&Alerts open it ,and set to max volume. I just forget to open it, so the SoundID can't play.